# Retrieve updated data from Database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0, winapp

I have an application without sources, using MySql DataBase 3.23, C# .net-4.0.

I can't update to the new version, and, I must retrieve the new data on update table. The trigger can't be used for this version. Of course I have user and password for log in. You help me please on how can I extract the new records? thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

```
CREATE TABLE PREPARATI ( 
    TIPO CHAR(1), 
    UNITA CHAR(30), 
    PARAMETRO CHAR(30) ,
    CODICE CHAR(30), 
    PRODOTTO CHAR(30), 
    LOTTO CHAR(30) ,
    FASE CHAR(30), 
    STATO smallint, 
    BEGIN_T int, 
    END_T int, 
    TOT_T int, 
    INCR_T int, 
    N_SAMPLES int, 
    TOT_Q float, 
    INCR_Q float, 
    GLOB_Q float, 
    MIN_Q float, 
    MAX_Q float, 
    CAUSA smallint, 
    FMT_COD CHAR(1),
    TIPO_COD smallint,
    CODES CHAR(254), 
    INDEX Xtime (BEGIN_T, END_T)
);
```

Instead of timestamps, there is a column that stores the time in milliseconds upon update. I need to retrieve the newly added record.

Comment: You're right...too much time in front of the monitor for this problem...thanks

Comment: ok so what do you want to do? You have a table that has a new timestamp since something to compare it to? You want to extract data and bail out of 3.23? (probably not). The question just lacks anything to chomp on. Show a table structure, something, in native form, not hand typed. And then with that table, describe what you want to do with it. Then, hey let's do that with all tables.

Comment: instead of timestamps, there is a column that stores the time in milliseconds when the update. I need to retrieve the newly added record. The table structure is below: [edit]CREATE TABLE PREPARATI (
TIPO     CHAR(1),
UNITA    CHAR(30), PARAMETRO CHAR(30) ,CODICE CHAR(30),
PRODOTTO CHAR(30), LOTTO     CHAR(30) ,FASE   CHAR(30),
STATO    smallint,
BEGIN_T  int, END_T int, TOT_T int, INCR_T int,
N_SAMPLES int,
TOT_Q     float, INCR_Q float, GLOB_Q float, MIN_Q float, MAX_Q float,
CAUSA smallint,
FMT_COD CHAR(1),TIPO_COD smallint,CODES CHAR(254),
INDEX Xtime (BEGIN_T, END_T));[edit]

Comment: from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) 3.23 is from year 2000. So I am thinking a windows xp dev box with visual studio 2005 would suit pretty well. You can get it off bizspark for free

Answer (score 0):

if i completely understand what you mean you want to write codes to retrieve information from a MySQL database so you are familiar with database programming and SQL commands
i assume you are familiar to connect to a SQL server database as a C# programmer knows it .
you can add appropriate reference for MySQL database and create an adapter and commands you need to retrieve data from database .

the dll you need is MySql.Data.dll  and the namespace to use is  MySql.Data
you can download it here : [MySQL.Data.dll download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html)

and if you need further clarifications and be familiar with its classes and methods i recommend to check this out :
[MySQL commands](http://www.functionx.com/mysqlnet/csharp/Lesson02.htm)

Comment: You're right. As I understand it, I can connect on MySQL 3.23 and retrieve data with connector 1.0. If so, how can I do coexist the two versions of the .NET connector? Thanks

Comment: I'd try to install .NET 1.0, but maybe the frameword required is only .NET 1.1, even if I've installed 4.5.. Is it possible it?

Comment: well as i say the truth i didnt face to such kinds of problems like this but as i read some texts about .NET it should be possible . and ofcourse newer versions must supports olders . have you ever try it ?

Comment: oh yes. all versions of connector can connect to MySQL Server that is at least release  4.01

Comment: the word coexist you use make my mind thinking about some bloody polymorphism techniques , sounds really a good challenge for me too to work on , whats the name and the version of software you want to update ?
and are you sure it connects directly to a database to update itself ? i mean are you sure there isnt any server handshaking and redirects between the update procedure

Comment: there are not linked server maybe, and nothig redirect. I must write a c# WinApp from zero that read the new record on update event in MySql 3.23 DataBase. My release of Mysql that I'm working for new app is 5.6

Comment: since when is the following true: `and ofcourse newer versions must supports olders` :>

Comment: I'd try with 6.3 release of connector, and the server must be at least 4.01.

Comment: [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-versions.html) there are the answer. Is it possible ?